# i got a html loop that works on a variable but it doesn't work

Tags: html, loops

hey this the code (its a loop with a timer) i need to be able to change the var via a button but atm it doesn't work

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<script>

var timer = 1000;
var counter = 0;

 var Timer = setInterval(function() {updateGem()},timer);
    function updateGem(){
        counter += 1
        document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = counter;

    }

function test(){
timer -= 1000;
}
</script>
<button onclick= "test();">button</button>
<h3 id=show></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `test` function doesn't actually do anything because you don't assign the result to any variable. Maybe you need something like `timer = <insert math here>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interval timing will not change when you update the variable. You need to clear the interval and then reinitialize it.

```
var timer = 1000;
var counter = 0;

var Timer = setInterval(function() {updateGem()},timer);
function updateGem(){
    counter += 1
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = counter;
}


function test(){
    timer -= 1000;
    clearInterval(Timer);
    Timer = setInterval(function() {updateGem()},timer);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your test() function does an operation but does not assign the result to any variables

```
function test(){
 timer -= 1000;
}
```

but timer is the interval. I think you want change the counter, so your test function becomes

```
function test(){
     counter = counter - 1000;
    }
```

Comment: o yeah sorry made a typo